# Get login / logout activity in Audit Trails for SharePoint 2010

Tags: forms-authentication, auditing

Is there anyway by which I can log the login/logout activity along with other user related activities like *Edit Profile, Change Password* etc. in a FBA configured 2010 SharePoint site?

I searched over the internet which stated that by default SharePoint does not provide any such facility.